# Does the following series converge or diverge? $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{9 \ln(x)}{x^8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have used the comparison test:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{9 \ln(x)}{x^8}$$

$$\frac{9 \ln(x)}{x^8}>\frac{1}{x^8}$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{9 \ln(x)}{x^8}$$

Is divergent.

I don't understand why this is wrong

Comment: Should that be $n^8$ in the denominator instead of $x^8$?

Comment: As it currently written, divergent. Are you sure that the variable is $x,$ not $n$?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9\ln(x)}{x^8}$ diverges when $x\neq 1$.  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{9\ln(n)}{n^8}$ converges.  Which did you want?

Comment: Sum of $\frac{1}{n^8}$ doesn't diverge. You should compare with $\frac{9}{n^7}$

Comment: The comparison test tells you that if $a_n > b_n$ **and** $\sum b_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. In this case (assuming the $x$ is supposed to be an $n$), $\sum b_n$ does not diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ and notice that $\frac{2}{n^2} > \frac{1}{n^2}$, so your argument says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2}$ diverges, which is wrong.

There are four possible relations between the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, with $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$ (or, at least for all $n > N$ for some constant $N$ -- since convergence/divergence is not decided by a finite initial segment of a series) that are similar to the argument you made.  (If you are not talking about sums of positive terms, you should first resolve absolute convergence/divergence.)  Suppose

- $\sum_n a_n$ converges.  Then all we know is that $\sum_n b_n$ is bigger than $\sum_n a_n$ -- it could converge to a larger number or it could diverge (to $+\infty$).
- $\sum_n b_n$ converges.  Then we know $\sum_n a_n$ converges (and $0 \leq \sum_n a_n \leq \sum_n b_n$).

[image: Comparison with a converging series]

- $\sum_n a_n$ diverges (necessarily to $+\infty$, since the sequence of partial sums is monotonically increasing).  Then $\sum_n b_n$ also diverges (to $+\infty$).
- $\sum_n b_n$ diverges.  Then we don't have any constraint on $\sum a_n$ -- it could converge or could also diverge (to $+\infty$).

[image]

It can sometimes help to use the wording:

- If the larger sum converges, it acts as a cap on the smaller sum, forcing it to converge.
- If the smaller sum diverges, it acts as a wedge forcing the larger sum to also diverge.

---

For your instant problem, it is more useful to proceed: for all $x > 0$,
$$  x > \ln x  \text{,}  $$
(Graph it.)  so
$$  \frac{1}{x^7} = \frac{x}{x^8} > \frac{\ln x}{x^8}  \text{.}  $$
Then
$$  \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^7} > \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^8}  \text{.}  $$
The sum of interest has nonnegative summands (so is (nonstrictly) monotonically increasing) and is bounded above by a convergent sum, so converges.  You should be able to handle the "$9$" on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that the series is larger than a convergent series.  That actually doesn't tell you anything about whether the series converges or not.  Roughly speaking, "if it is smaller than finite, it's finite; if it is bigger than infinite, it's infinite".  But "bigger than finite" doesn't tell you whether it's just a larger finite amount or whether it really is infinite.  $3$ and $\infty$ are both larger than $2$ for example.

What you need is to find something larger than it which converges, or something smaller than it which diverges.  Consider $1/x^7$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$u_n=\frac{\ln(n)}{n^8}$$

You might see that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n^2u_n=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n^5}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0$$

thus, for $ n $ great enough,

$$0<n^2u_n<1$$
or
$$0<u_n<\frac{1}{n^2}$$
by comparison test, it converges.

Comment: Is it possible to use the integral test for this serie?

Comment: @MengenLiu Yes, both ( integral and series) are called 's of Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

*With asymptotic Analysis*:

$\ln n=o(x)$, so $\:\dfrac{\ln x}{x^8}=o\Bigl(\dfrac 1{x^7}\Bigr)$, which is a convergent $p$-series.